# How can I handle click two ImageView's in item of ListView

Tags: android, xml, model-view-controller, view

I've item in ListView and I need set handle for onClick for two items with ids R.id.accept & R.id.cancel. But setOnClick for these two items not work. Ho can I do that? If I set onCLickListener then in not work simple. I add example xml-layout my item which I need draw in ListView. ....
....
...
..

Thank you!

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/cardView"
        app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/colorWhite"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        app:cardCornerRadius="20dp"
        app:cardElevation="2dp"
        android:layout_margin="8dp">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/leftContainer"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:gravity="center">

                <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
                    android:id="@+id/avatar"
                    android:layout_width="64dp"
                    android:layout_height="64dp"
                    android:contentDescription="@null"
                    android:src="@drawable/placeholder_photo"/>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/starContainer"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                        android:src="@drawable/star_false"/>

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                        android:src="@drawable/star_false"/>

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                        android:src="@drawable/star_false"/>

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                        android:src="@drawable/star_false"/>

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                        android:src="@drawable/star_false"/>

                </LinearLayout>

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:maxLength="5"
                    android:text="0.0/5"
                    android:maxLines="1"/>

            </LinearLayout>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@id/leftContainer">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/name"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:ellipsize="end"
                    android:maxLines="2"
                    android:gravity="start"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:text="Loading..."/>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                    android:layout_below="@id/name"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:baselineAligned="false">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/currency"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:gravity="end"
                        android:maxLines="1"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/price"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                        android:maxLines="1"
                        android:ellipsize="end"
                        android:maxLength="8"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:textSize="22sp"/>

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/accept"
                        android:layout_width="44dp"
                        android:layout_height="44dp"
                        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                        android:src="@drawable/search_icon_accept"
                        android:contentDescription="@null"
                        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                        android:clickable="false"
                        android:focusable="false"
                        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"/>

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/cancel"
                        android:layout_width="44dp"
                        android:layout_height="44dp"
                        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                        android:src="@drawable/search_icon_cancel"
                        android:contentDescription="@null"
                        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                        android:clickable="false"
                        android:focusable="false"
                        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"/>

                </LinearLayout>

            </RelativeLayout>


        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/progressContainer"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="#80FFFFFF"
            android:visibility="gone">

            <ProgressBar
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>

        </RelativeLayout>

    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>


</FrameLayout>
```

ADAPTER:

```
    @Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View view = View.inflate(getContext(), R.layout.dialog, parent);
    view.findViewById(R.id.accept).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            
        }
    });
    view.findViewById(R.id.cancel).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            
        }
    });
    return view;
}
```

Comment: please show your adapter

Comment: added to main post